# Extract and combine all text child nodes

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a node list created by appending text child nodes dynamically as following:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  let containerChild = document.createTextNode('a')
   container.appendChild(containerChild)
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Assuming that only text nodes are appended, what is the fastest / most clean way to extract the full text? In the case above, I am looking to get the string `aaaaa`. Of course I can loop through the parent node `container` to extract each child and then combine them. Just wondering if there is a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.textContent` of the parent will combine them automatically:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  let containerChild = document.createTextNode('a')
   container.appendChild(containerChild)
}

const text = container.textContent;
console.log(text, text.length);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

(`.innerHTML` works too)